# Printing a reverse list in python

Tags: list, reverse

In the following code I got None, why ?
Thanks,

numbers = [10, 15, 20, 30]

print(numbers)

print(numbers.reverse())

numbers.reverse()

print(numbers)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at that operation in the documentation of the [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), you will see this note:

> The reverse() method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when reversing a large sequence. To remind users that it operates by side effect, it does not return the reversed sequence.

So `numbers.reverse()` won't return anything but will still change the order of the list.